# Making one Cell Disabled untill another Button is Selected in TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, tableview, uitableview

I am trying to create two custom buttons in a table VIew Cell, What I want to achieve is that  when One button in a specific Cell is selected only then the user should be able to select The other button in the same Cell, I tried keeping a check for indexpath for a button to be selected but didn't work.....can ne one just help me out here?????

Answer (score 0):

Write an if statement in the cell and toggle each other:

```
//this is for button 1
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{

  [sender setSelected:!sender.selected];

  if (sender.selected){
     [button2 setIsEnabled:YES];
  }
}
```

Comment: but I dnt get the button2 instance in the IbAction both are being Created at in CellForRowAtIndexPAth, I tried keeping the if condition based on index path...didnt work

Comment: You can do this logic on cellForRow... or in the actual cell class. You should create your own cell subclass and add this method to it

Comment: I dnt get it,..In cell for Index Path if I try to check for [button setSelected] it never comes true, and also I had tried Using my own custom Cell but the problem with that was that, when i clicked one button the entire row used to get selected.hence I went for this method